# No FBSession in Facebook iOS SDK 4.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

There is no more class `FBSession` in new Facebook iOS SDK v4.x. How can I find out whether user is logged in or not now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ?

Comment: "FBSession.activeSession has been replaced with [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] and FBSDKLoginManager. There is no concept of session state. Instead, use the manager to login and this sets the currentAccessToken reference." from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vincent is right, check [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] to determine if the user is logged in.

Comment: do you know how to log the user out, i need to do that programatically

Comment: The FBSDKLoginManager has a logout method, but the online docs are currently blank. I have yet to convert to 4.0 and I have the same need. Check out the headers until https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/ is finished.

Comment: do you know how to fetch the user info after a successful login, i need to get the email

Comment: Please how can I replace this `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];` ?

Answer (score 5):

To check if the user logged in and if so, navigate to another view:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    // User is logged in
    [self performSelector:@selector(accessGrantedNavigation)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void)accessGrantedNavigation{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueLoginFB" sender: self];
}
```

To log out: 
(although it doesn't allow to change FB user. I think it is because Safari already takes care of that session and remains the same user.)

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [manager logOut];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please how can I replace this `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];` ?

Comment: @NeAS can you help with replacing [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO] ?